# MySQL Multiple COUNT() with different conditions in single QUERY

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure

```
id  | season
1   | 1
2   | 1
2   | 2
3   | 2
4   | 2
5   | 1
```

I want the query to return the count of the the **total** IDs like:

```
total_season2  | new | existing
      3        |  2  |    1
```

I can do it with multiple Queries or using php but I want to have the results in a single query

Comment: What defines a row as new or existing?

Comment: @Tristan The Season. In this case I can use WHERE season=2

Comment: I'm still not clear on what `new` and `existing` represent? In the example data you provided you expect `new` = 2 and `existing` = 1. I can't see how you can get this result from the example data you provided. What defines a row as new or existing? Do you mean `new` is where `season == 1`, and `existing` where `season == 2`?

Comment: @Tristan Sorry for the confusion. is more like: total_season WHERE season==2, new WHERE ID occurs(exist's) only once , existing WHERE ID  occurs()exist's more than once

Comment: @Tristan It would be very helpfull if you could edit the question to understandable to make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need to select all the rows you can use an empty select with subqueries to get the data you want. There may be more efficient ways to getting the same data, but this will work:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM seasons s WHERE s.season = 2) as total_season2,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM seasons s WHERE s.season = 2 AND (SELECT distinct COUNT(ss.id) FROM seasons ss WHERE ss.id = s.id) = 1) as new,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM seasons s WHERE s.season = 2 AND (SELECT distinct COUNT(ss.id) FROM seasons ss WHERE ss.id = s.id) > 1) as existing
```